# Selection Highlighting - NeoVim - LazyVim - Lua

Tags: lua, neovim

How do I change the way my highlighting looks when I select text in Visual mode in neovim, so that it matches the colors that are already being used in the color scheme? I'm new to neovim, so I'm not very familiar with it yet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was it! - hi! Visual cterm=reverse gui=reverse